# Is it safe to remove SD and sim card while phone is powering on and off?

Tags: sd-card, sim-card, htc-one

i noticed someone was removing and putting in the SD and sim card while my phone was powering on and off, and i wanted to know if this is safe or if it can cause issues with the phone?

Also they were repairing my phone charging port and said that i encrypted the phone, which i never once did. So i wanted to know if these 2 things were linked or if they could of accidently encrypt it while opening the phone? I'm veryy confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concerned term is hot swapping

External storage (including SD card) should only be removed after it has been unmounted from the system, which ensures that no data gets to be read from or written into the device, so as to prevent data corruption and app crashes. Android supports hot swapping of external storage. However, since there is no way to fully ascertain visibly at what stage of shutdown process the external storage is unmounted, it should be removed only when the phone has powered off.

As for the SIM card, OEMs including Google recommends powering off the device before inserting or removing a SIM card. On the other hand, many Android users since Marshmallow have had success with hot swapping a SIM card just by turning Airplane mode on and off. Some phones explicitly support SIM card hot swapping, such as Samsung Galaxy S7.

Android devices [since Android Lollipop](https://www.engadget.com/2015/03/02/android-lollipop-automatic-encryption/) comes encrypted, unless they have been [exempted](https://source.android.com/compatibility/9/android-9-cdd.pdf) (see heading 9.9) owing to major performance degradation from encryption.

Comment: Great answer! But I have been able to hot swap a SIM card in Android 5.1 (Lollipop) before (although it took a few minutes to register the SIM card changes).

Comment: @Zackary, me too, but I read somewhere that people could hot swap instantaneously only since Marshmallow. :-)

Comment: I must add my voice here to say.  My SDCard works, but not in the phone, after a hot-swapping took place.  I wish the tech had turned it off, or unmounted the SDCard.  We did not notice that the SDCard quit.  I'm attempting to diagnose the SD-Card now, I've attempted many re-seats.  I can read it with my PC.